# How to inject document.body in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to add some text in **showlist.component.html**. My code is given below, I am not aware how to use `document.body` in Angular 2.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-showlist',
  templateUrl: './showlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showlist.component.css']
})
export class ShowlistComponent implements OnInit {

public myname = "saurabh";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
//this.myname.appendTo(document.body);
document.body(this.myname);
 //document.write(this.myname);
  }

}
```

Comment: You _can_ use it exactly like that. `document.body` returns the `<body>` HTML element. In your case above, `document.write(this.myname);` should replace all the body contents with `saurabh`. If you want to reference a specific element, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/3777524)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you do the following to access the `document.body`

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-showlist',
  templateUrl: './showlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showlist.component.css']
})
export class ShowlistComponent implements OnInit {
  public myname = "saurabh";

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.document.body.innerHTML = this.myname;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure it's kind advanced stuff but I will try my best, `DOCUMENT` is dependency injection(aka DI) token that your component depend on it to refer to the Document and for  non-class dependencies (as it's not a class) we need the `@Inject` decorator

Comment: `this.document.body.innerHTML = this.myname;` , if i want to add `this.myname` with other page data, then what i need to do ?  The above line is only showing `this.myname` on the page and erasing everything else

Comment: `DOCUMENT` in `@angular/platform-browser` is deprecated, changing to `@angular/common`

Comment: FYI: I had to automatically import using my IDE: it came up as this:  import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_tokens";